# Modifying the horizontal axis in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please how do i modify the horizontal axis to start from  1959-01-01 to 2013-01-01

[image]

Comment: [This](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-scale-of-the-horizontal-category-axis-in-a-chart-637897f6-0d51-4ec5-bef9-25d2c83a8450) may be of use

Comment: OK, it's a pain. you need to format the axis properties and change the minimum and maximum values to display. The problem is that excels data formatting is really odd. you'll need to find the excel date code for the ones you want - you can do this by changing the formatting of a cell *from* date to something else - you'll get a long (8 characters?) code which is how excel stores dates....

Comment: You get a number, which is the number of days starting with `January 1st, 1900` (which is `1`). You can also use a formula: `=NUMBERVALUE(01/01/1959)` should give you `21551`